# Code completion in Netbeans IDE, or other

Tags: javascript, netbeans, ide, code-completion

I have a bit specific question, but it is me bothering quite a while, so if you know answer, please help. In netbeans (I encountered this problem also in sublime text), that when I type " (double quote), the IDE automaticaly add next " and put the cursor in the between those double quotes, like this:

```
"|"
```

This is ok with me. The issue is, that from some time (I had maybe type some Ctrl+ something shortcut) it works somehow different, I have to type two double quotes "" to have netbeans type "" for me, also the cursor is not in the middle but after the quotes, like this:

```
""|
```

Please help me restore this behaviour, thank you!
PS: I googled a bit but no luck with this specific question.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a **bug**, But to help you in this go to tools>option menu of netbeans and tell us which key map scheme you are using [image]

Comment: I am using plain NetBeans. I already reinstaled whole NetBeans so it is working as expected, but it is not the first time it happend. It is driving me crazy. Also, it is not only NetBeans, I encountered it also in SublimeText, so maybe it is windows problem

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling Netbeans solved this issue. Can not find any other answer on the internet.